# How to write an update query to subtract a certain value?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Is this right way to perform the subtraction operation in case of prepared statement in the sql query ?

```
$sql = "UPDATE users set credits = (credits-$price) WHERE username = ?";
```

Code to subtracted the user credits based on the value of $price

```
$price = $row0['price'];
    
    $sql = "UPDATE users set credits = (credits-$price) WHERE username = ?;";
        $stmt1 = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt1, $sql)) {
                $db_err = array("error" => "Database");
                echo json_encode($db_err);
            } else {
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt1, "s", $_SESSION['username']);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);
```

Comment: No, this is not the right way in the case of prepared statements, because you are concatenating a value into the query.

Comment: Use `(credits - ?)` and bind that value as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a placeholder for your `$price` variable to properly use prepared statements. Concatenating the value is *never* safe unless you are able to compare the value with a list of possible values.

```
$sql = "UPDATE users set credits = (credits - ?) WHERE username = ?;";

mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt1, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt1, "ss", $price, $_SESSION['username']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);
```

---

Note that it's better to use object syntax for [many reasons](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect#procedural). Here is how you do that:

```
$stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE users set credits = (credits - ?) WHERE username = ?");
$stmt1->bind_param("ss", $price, $_SESSION['username']);
$stmt1->execute();
```

Comment: Please note that procedural interface is inferior to object for [many reasons](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect#procedural) and it's better to use the latter providing an example.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Can you double check my answer addition please. I'm not very familiar with mysqli, I almost exclusively use PDO.

Comment: is there any difference between i and s cant it be ss

Comment: actually the value of price is in decimal

Comment: @Jskccc you can safely use s all the time

Comment: Using d for for the exact-type values will lead to obvious errors.

Comment: @Your Common Sense  But price is not string
The "sss" argument lists the types of data that the parameters are. The s character tells mysql that the parameter is a string. I am confused here.
The argument may be one of four types:
i - integer
d - double
s - string
b - BLOB

Comment: @Jskccc Almost everything can be a string. It's best to use string whenever you can

Comment: @Jskccc if you are interested in the theory, read up on the fixed type values in mysql. If you are interested in the answer, you should use s for the decimal field.